# MoviePy shows frames as tiles across video

Tags: python, moviepy

I have this weird bug with moviePy. I'm creating a video using [VideoClip](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/getting_started/videoclips.html?highlight=videoclip#videoclip) where frames are defined using numpy arrays.

For the example, I'm using a single frame that looks like this (when printed with matplotlib)

```
plt.imshow(frame)
plt.show()
```

[image]

When I create a video using only this frame, it looks like this:

```
def get_frame(t):
    return frame

animation = VideoClip(get_frame, duration=3)
animation.ipython_display(fps=3, codec='mpeg4')
```

[image]

**Why does moviepy repeat the frame instead of stretching it?**

I've tried playing with the video size etc, but nothing changed.

---

Here's the whole code:

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoClip
import numpy as np

frame = np.zeros([400, 400])
frame[10:40,50:80] = 100

plt.imshow(frame)
plt.show()

def get_frame(t):
    return frame

animation = VideoClip(get_frame, duration=3)
animation.ipython_display(fps=3, codec='mpeg4')
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem: The numpy array should be 3D and what I had was 1D. Fixing this solved it.

Comment: Great answer. This is correct. The same is true for any greyscale images; they must be converted to RGB images first otherwise the bug persists.